# Merge Multiple JSON and Multiple level of Group By in C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, merge, .net-core

I'm trying to merge multiple JSON files which has the same type of data inside them and fetch the merged data from those JSONs. For example below are two JSON files.

JSON 1

```
[
{
    "Name": "Sample1",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Name": "Sample1 Sub1",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Name": "XXX",
                    "ID": ["278924"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Name": "Sample2",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Name": "Sample2 Sub1",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Name": "XXX",
                    "ID": ["278378"]
                },
                {
                    "Name": "YYY",
                    "ID": ["278289"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

JSON 2

```
[
{
    "Name": "Sample1",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Name": "Sample1 Sub1",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Name": "XXX",
                    "ID": ["357896"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Name": "Sample2",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Name": "Sample2 Sub1",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Name": "XXX",
                    "ID": ["356842"]
                },
                {
                    "Name": "YYY",
                    "ID": ["357123"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I'm expecting the output to be in the below format.

```
[
{
    "Name": "Sample1",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Name": "Sample1 Sub1",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Name": "XXX",
                    "ID": ["278924, 357896"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Name": "Sample2",
    "Data": [
        {
            "Name": "Sample2 Sub1",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "Name": "XXX",
                    "ID": ["278378,356842"]
                },
                {
                    "Name": "YYY",
                    "ID": ["278289,357123"]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I'm not sure where to start this. I tried groupby for multiple level but couldn't able to fetch the result in expected format. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: @Matthew I tried to deserialize the JSON into List in Class format and group by from there which ended in multiple loops. I don't have any code handy, I'm parallely working on this now.